# Log messages to console when running tests in Travis CI

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, travis-ci

Is there a way to log a message to the Travis console? I have tried System.out.println() without much luck. The closes to any docs I can find is https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/travis-ci/VYpwYaiKfSA

Comment: What do you want to log? If it's something from gradle refer to http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/logging.html

Comment: @rciovati, thanks for the link. However we were trying to debug the Travis running environment. We had a test that was using time difference of System.currentTimeMillis(). The test passed flawlessly in our local machine, but failed in Travis. We figured the difference was probably the speed of our local machine, but I wanted to throw some logs to test that theory.

Comment: @RalphPina were you able?

Comment: @natario this was 3 years ago. I haven't used Travis in a while...

Comment: @RalphPina that's fine, thanks :) ended up using adb logcat in a separate process.

Answer (score 2):

The recommended way is to output something to either stdout or stderr. If these messages aren't redirected somewhere else (log file or /dev/null), they'll be dumped into the build's log output, and should be visible, as we collect both streams (stderr and stdout).